# CSS/HTML navigation centering confusion

Tags: html, css

so this is how my navigation looks: 
[image]

Quite unbalanced right.. my minds kinda fkd up. I have no idea what I am doing already. I'd like to ask some help how to center it out. This is the code of the css:

```
.navigation {
    width: 886px;
    height: 84px;

    background: url('../img/nav_bg.png') no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none outside;
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-left: 63px;
}

.navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none; 
}

.navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I suggest you to give a look at a different approach if you want to be really cross-browser :) Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might be able to help you here. To center your `li`'s with flexbox all you would have to do is add these styles to `.navigation ul`

```
.navigation ul{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: @Fur Add this style `align-items:center;` to your `ul` also and see if that works. You may have to also give your `ul` a height... like `100%` or the 84px to match the wrapper

Comment: So this is how it looks now: http://prntscr.com/6om7rm and this is the code: http://prntscr.com/6om7zl

Comment: @Fur Is it because of the `padding-left: 63px;` on the `ul`?

Comment: It looks perfect now: http://prntscr.com/6ommhw thank you so much. Is there any way I can balance it from left to right?

Comment: @Fur make sure your `ul` is the exact same width as your red image background with no padding and margin. it should be perfectly center. if it still looks off, look at your `li`'s for any extra margin or padding

Answer (score 2):

### Flexbox is not yet 100% supported cross-browser

As you can see from this link: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

**Flebox** nowadays is quite well supported but if you carefully look at those symbols on each square you notice that the support is not full but partial on some browsers (especially mobile).

**Global (with prefix)**
82.47%  +   10.5%   =   92.97%

**unprefixed:**
71.8%   +   0.38%   =   72.18%

You should to add a prefix if you really want to use it.

**

### Using a different method - display:table;

**

On the other hand, I suggest you to use another approach which is much more stable and supported on all browsers:

Look at the support of **display:table;**

**Link:** http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Atable

To solve your problem you can remove all your padding-top with fixed values and use vertical-align:middle and display:table-cell. This way no matter what is the height of the ul it will be always vertically centered.

- **Center horizontally** the `ul` element using `text-align:center;`
- **Center vertically** the ul by setting the **.navigation** container with `display:table;` and the ul element with `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;`

Code example:

```
.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 84px;
    background: lightgrey;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
}

.navigation ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none outside;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}    

.navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none; 
}

.navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Check **Jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/bmkspm69/1/

Comment: This is a good approach. I usually try to support flexbox as much as possible, because it is more manageable (more configurable with less styles) and I want to support the forward thinking approach that I feel will be the standard in the future. In practice, I find the major pitfall (excluding IE 8 and below - _not required for the projects I build_) are the iOS browsers. For this I use a media query and use the above styles.

Comment: And yes, go with the pre-fix version if you go the flexbox route

Comment: Wow, amazing thank you so much Alex! It is fixed now! I am looking for it to be balanced from left to right, this is the look of my navigatin now: http://prntscr.com/6ommhw

Answer (score 0):

Give a `text-align: center` to the ul.
In general, for centering some elements inside a parent, parent should have `text-align:center` and the childs should have `display: inline-block` or `display: inline`.
HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
width: 400px;
text-align: center;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
}
```